# How to use a value from a query into another query in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code in my view:

```
# default group view for group admins
def adminGroupView(request):
    # get group id => group data and messages
    group_id = GroupUser.objects.get(username_id=request.user.id)
    groupdata = Group.objects.get(group_id=group_id)
    groupmessages =  MessageBoard.objects.filter(group_id=group_id)
    groupmembers = GroupUser.objects.filter(group_id=group_id)
    form = SendMessageForm()
    context = {
        "groupdata":groupdata,
        "groupmessages":groupmessages,
        "groupmembers":groupmembers,
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, 'base/group-admin.html', context)
```

I keep getting a typeerror

TypeError at /group/
Field 'group_id' expected a number but got <GroupUser: 9>.

when i replace the group_id with a number, the code works just fine. How do i use the value from the other query.

model

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)  
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.group_id)

class GroupUser(models.Model):
    group_id = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.group_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model.get()` can only return 1 object, it is safe to access the attribute it right there. When 0 or more than 1 objects are found, this method will error. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

Since your field `group_id` is a reference (`foreign key`) to `Group`, you can just get the group by calling:

```py
group = GroupUser.objects.get(username_id=request.user.id).group_id
```

In the above query, you fetch the related object of the type `Group`. To get the group_id specifically, you can do this:

```py
group_id = GroupUser.objects.get(username_id=request.user.id).group_id.group_id
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same type error

Comment: What is your `GroupUser` and `Group` model? Can you edit it in? And in which field can the `group_id` be found in that object?

Comment: I've added the model

Comment: I've edited the (hopefully working) answer in as well

Comment: it worked, thanks